# Autosum Cells VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to autosum the values within a block of cells in Excel using VBA. I kept getting a type mismatch error while debugging the following code. Where did I go wrong?

```
Sub autosumtest()
    Dim total As Integer
    Worksheets("Sheet1Test").Select
    Range("F16:G20").Select
    total = CInt("=SUM(Selection.Values)")
    MsgBox (total)
End Sub
```

**`EDIT 1:` Here is the simple sample of my test data called Autosum Range:**

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `CInt` - it won't help you sum the numbers if they are text?

Comment: If your data is numeric then a single line - without `CInt` - will suffice `MsgBox Application.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1Test").Range("F16:G20"))`

Comment: I thought using CInt would get rid of the type mismatch error

Comment: Do you have any cells with errors in the range being added?

Comment: Can you pls post a snapshot of your data? (Unless you have any of the codes below working)

Comment: @brettdj Ok, i've edited my question to include the snapshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [] to evaluate any spreadsheet expression.

```
Sub autosumtest()
   Dim total As Integer
   total = CInt([=sum(sheet1Test!F16:G20)])
   MsgBox (total)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for a new feature, somehow I've never managed to notice it.
Also `total = CInt(Evaluate("=sum(sheet1Test!F16:G20)"))` does the same job.

Answer (score 2):

Your range `F16 to G20` will contain different formats. Make sure they have the `Number` formatting and problem solved.

You can also use the following;

```
Sub autosumtest()
    Dim total As Integer
    total = [=SUM(Sheet1Test!F16:G20)]
    MsgBox (total)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the hell to you keep this .Select which is 100% useless ?

Comment: @iDevlop, if you call the macro from a different Sheet you'll need it, no? That's why I added the comment.

Comment: You need not. You *never* need to Select before evaluating or acting on a cell from VBA.  That's just slow behaviour probably inherited from looking at the Recorder's results.

Comment: @iDevlop, but I'm using on a worksheet and not a cell. You tell me this then, if I'm in Sheet4 and call the autosumtest then it will calculate the sum in Sheet4. Whereas now it will select Sheet1 and run the macro there. Or is my logic completely wrong ..?

Comment: Just use sum(sheet1Test!F16:G20)

Comment: t.thielemans Thanks for your reply. I got a runtime error '13' type missmatch after using your code and selecting the cells->Format Cells->Number->Decimal places: 0->Ok. Why am I still getting this type mismatch?

Comment: Thank you very much. Why did you remove the sheet name? Won't keeping the sheet name make the code more error proof?

Comment: @Anthony, in my test environment I didn't need the Sheet reference and I copy/pasted my solution. Apologies and edited one last time. Unfortunately I was too slow :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a type mismatch, as "=SUM(F16:G20)" is a string.

Worksheetfunction should be used for summing a desired range. Unless there's a wish to something further with selection, .Select is not needed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub autosumtest()
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1Test").Range("F16:G20")
       total = CInt(WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng))
    MsgBox (total)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 It worked! Thanks for reminding me about Option Explicit, introducing me to the use of "Set", as well as writing the code so efficiently and concisely.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, given the length of *some* the other answers and the redundant `CInt`....

```
Sub Easy()
MsgBox Application.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1Test").Range("F16:G20"))
End Sub
```

Comment: ... because my copy and paste skills are poor. Missing parentheses added.

Comment: I even tried putting in the parentheses but i'm still getting syntax error: MsgBox (Application.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1Test").Range("F16:G20"))

Comment: Thanks it worked. I never knew you could use MsgBox without the ()? Thats interesting.